# GridView in a tab fragment is displayed only after scrolling to that tab second time

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, android-gridview

I have a fragment for a tab which displays JSON parsed results in GridView. The results are not displayed when scrolled to that tab for first time. But after switching tabs, results are displayed in second visit.

```html
public class StoresFragment extends Fragment {
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private ArrayList<String> storenamefinal = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> imagelinksfinal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private GridView gridview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.stores_layout,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_stores);
        loading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.proStores);

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            new getData(getActivity()).execute();
        }

    }

        


    private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private Context context;

        public getData(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String url = Config1.DATA_URL;
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            return null;
        }

        private void showJSON(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                
                int i = result.length();
                Log.i("Result", result.toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    storenamefinal.add(null);
                    imagelinksfinal.add(null);
                }
                String temp;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    JSONObject Data = result.getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("Data", Data.toString());
                    temp = (Data.getString("mainpriority"));
                    Log.i("temp", temp.toString());
                    storenamefinal.set(Integer.parseInt(temp) - 1, Data.getString("storename"));

                    Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
                    imagelinksfinal.add(R.drawable.sg1);

                }
                Log.i("Result Length", storenamefinal.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), storenamefinal.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (storenamefinal != null) {
                final GridAdapterStores gridadapter = new GridAdapterStores(getActivity(), storenamefinal, imagelinksfinal);
                gridview.setAdapter(gridadapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter.

```html
public class GridAdapterStores extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> storename = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public GridAdapterStores(Context c, ArrayList<String> storename, ArrayList<Integer> imagelinks) {
        context = c;
        this.imagelinks = imagelinks;
        this.storename = storename;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return storename.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid;
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_stores, parent, false);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        TextView textViewStoreName = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
        // ImageView imageViewStoreImage = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.store_image);
        textViewStoreName.setText(storename.get(position));
         //  Integer x=imagelinks.get(position);
        //  imageViewStoreImage.setImageResource(x);
        return grid;
    }
}
```

And also, everytime tab is switched, gridview gets added, but data is displayed in only one gridview.